# xts problem with dynlm

Tags: r, statistics, xts, zoo

I am trying to use xts as much as possible in my time series work as it seems to be the suggested way of doing things. However, I have getting a strange error.

CPI.NSA and INT are xts objects.

```
library(dynlm)
CPI.NSA.x <- CPI.NSA[dr1]
INT.x <- INT[dr1]

CPI.NSA.z <- as.zoo(CPI.NSA.x)
INT.z <- as.zoo(INT.x)

> dynlm(CPI.NSA.z ~ INT.z + L(CPI.NSA.z, 1))

Time series regression with "zoo" data:
Start = 1953-02-01, End = 1971-06-01

Call:
dynlm(formula = CPI.NSA.z ~ INT.z + L(CPI.NSA.z, 1))

Coefficients:
    (Intercept)            INT.z  L(CPI.NSA.z, 1)  
     -0.0006795        1.0440174       -0.0869050  


> dynlm(CPI.NSA.x ~ INT.x + L(CPI.NSA.x, 1))
Error in `[.xts`(a, match0(indexes, attr(a, "index")), , drop = FALSE) : 
  i is out of range
```

It was my understanding that whenever I have a function that takes zoo, I can pass it an xts and it should just work, but clearly that is not the case here.

What's going on?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You say

> It was my understanding that whenever
>   I have a function that takes zoo, I
>   can pass it an xts and it should just
>   work, but clearly that is not the case
>   here.

and I am wondering if you think that `zoo` and `xts` are identical. They are not -- `xts` extends `zoo` in useful ways at the prices of limiting the index types to actual time or date objects (rather than arbitrary indices as for `zoo`).

Now, `dynlm` is written by Achim Zeileis who is one of the authors of `zoo` as I don't see why you can't keep your data in `xts` but then pass to `zoo` (via, e.g., `as.zoo(foo)`) when calling the `dynlm` functions.

There is no magic 'downcast'. But you can do it by hand.  Which is what you are doing in the first part of your question. Ok?

Comment: THanks for the clarification. That makes sense. I didn't think they were identical, but I wasn't clear on when they could or could not be interchanged.

Answer (score 1):

the simple answer is that zoo and xts are not completely interchangeable, although sometimes they are.

This is a really good example of a time when they are not interchangeable.